# Xcode 13 auto building problem (indexing)

Tags: swift, xcode, build, auto

I'm using Xcode 13 and I didn't have such problems in Xcode 12 now I don't know what to do. I get built automatically my app after the slightest change (Even one space).

If I leave even a space, it is constantly trying to build. I can't write code anymore.

Comment: I am *certainly* not an Xcode authority - I know just enough to be dangerous and put things on the App Store! And yes, call me very unimpressed with Xcode 13. I'd consider it to be almost as bad as Visual Studio back when I used it - very.... HEAVY. Two thoughts. First, does a (fairly) new project have this behavior? Second, have you dug through Xcode preferences? (I just did and nothing immediately jumped out at me. Also, my build times are much longer but *not* forever indexing. Have you tried deleting your derived data?

Comment: Is this a SwiftUI project?

Comment: @liquid no, it is not.

Comment: @dfd I tired them yes. but there was no difference. It is not a new project. it was my old project. Only I moved my project to a different MacBook and I try to use it with xcode13 but it is making a problem I couldn't understand